# Why can't I create a new Camera.Size object?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In a test fixture I am trying to create a mock Android.Hardware.Camera.Size object like this:

```
var test = new Android.Hardware.Camera.Size(12, 10);
```

But I get the following compiler error:

> Cannot access protected member
>   'Android.Hardware.Camera.Size.Size(System.IntPtr,
>   Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)' via a qualifier of type
>   `Android.Hardware.Camera.Size'. The qualifier must be of type
>   'TestCtrlz.Fixtures' or derived from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! I was looking at the Andoid API docs. The mono ported object requires a reference to a cCamera object in the public constructor, so:

```
var test = new Android.Hardware.Camera.Size(null, 12, 10);
```

does the trick for a mock object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to create the `Size` object yourself, but some methods gives you back that kind of object.
For example you can retrieve the list of supported preview sizes using :

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters()
List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
```